# Google Earth Engine: Supervised Classification fusion table error

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, classification

[image]

I am currently doing a supervised classification (just two classes for detection of large-scale solar plants) in GEE. When I am using training polygons drew and create as polygons everything works just fine but when I use the same training polygons as a fusion table (made from KML) I keep getting this message. Here is the sample of the code.

```
var trainingData = solarDenmark;

// Train Sample Data
// Select Bands
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'nd', 'NDWI'];
var input = sentinelComposite.select(bands);
var classifierTraining = input.select(bands)
      .sampleRegions({
        collection: trainingData,
        properties: ['solar'],
        scale: 30
      });

// Instantiate a CART and train it:
var classifier = ee.Classifier.randomForest(10).train({
  features: classifierTraining, 
  classProperty: 'solar', 
  inputProperties: bands
});

//Classify the image
var classified = input.select(bands).classify(classifier).clip(region2);
```

Comment: Share your fusion table and post a link to your code using the 'get link' button next to the 'save' button in the code editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `system:index` column from the Fusion Table prior to loading in EE.